# Converting async responce of Array of Arrays into Object

Tags: arrays, angular, observable, data-conversion

I am trying to convert Array of Arrays that I get from Observable into single array of objects. This is my code:

```
    this.jobsService.jobsUpdated.pipe(
    map(
     (jobsData)=> {
      return jobsData.map(
        (job)=>{
        return  job.parts.map((part)=>{ return part })
        }
      )
     }
    )
   ).subscribe(
      (partsData)=>{
         console.log('partsdata', partsData)
      }
    );
```

This is the data format I am getting back:

```
    [
     [
       {partName:1, number:10, quantity: 100}
     ],
     [
       {partName:2, number:20, quantity: 200},
       {partName:3, number:30, quantity: 300}
     ],
     etc...
    ]
```

Please help to convert this data, hopefully in the pipe method, into :

```
    [
      {partName:1, number:10, quantity: 100},
      {partName:2, number:20, quantity: 200},
      {partName:3, number:30, quantity: 300}
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `reduce` and no need of using inner `map`

Why `reduce`? - To generate single output based on multiple inputs.

```
this.jobsService.jobsUpdated.pipe(
    map((jobsData)=> {
      return jobsData.reduce(
        (acc, job)=>{
          acc.push(...job.parts)
          return acc;
        }
      , [])
    })
);
```

---

Alternatively `concat` can also be used

```
this.jobsService.jobsUpdated.pipe(
   (jobsData)=> jobsData.reduce(
      (acc, job)=> acc.concat(job.parts), [])
   })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a flat array:

```js
this.jobsService.jobsUpdated
  .pipe(
     pluck('parts'),
     map((parts)=> parts.flat())
  )
```

Comment: Not sure, how it will make sure to extract `parts` property only?

Comment: Yes, I forgot about this insignificant detail, I'll add it now

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I did not know about pluck. I will learn more about it.